# Get value from parameter store via code pipeline output '***'

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-codebuild

Base on [AWS Code Build documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeBuild.html#action-reference-CodeBuild-config), we can pass `EnvironmentVariables` with `PARAMETER_STORE` type.

I've ensure the parameter store name is **typed correctly** and the parameter is **exists**.

I've tried to login via aws cli but it seem not related and still get wrong result.

Here is my cloudformation yaml snippet:

```
- Name: Build
  Actions:
    - Name: HelloWord
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Build
        Owner: AWS
        Provider: CodeBuild
        Version: "1"
      Configuration:
        ProjectName: HelloWoldBuild
        EnvironmentVariables: 
          Fn::Sub:
            - '[{"name": "NGINX_BASE_IMAGE_TAG","value": "${NGINX_BASE_IMAGE_TAG}","type": "PARAMETER_STORE"}]
            - NGINX_BASE_IMAGE_TAG: "/nginx/base"
```

and here is my `buildspec.yaml` snippet:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 18
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "${NGINX_BASE_IMAGE_TAG}"
```

When I see the CodeBuild log, the output was '***'. The correct one should be value from my parameter store.

How could it happen ? I still don't get it. I've test with `PLAINTEXT` type and works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design.

Values from parameter store are **considers as sensitive**.

So CodeBuild masks them so they don't appear in **plain text in its logs**.

To deal with that, you can assign it to **different variable**, and print that. The following would be my first try to deal with that:

```
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - NEW_VAR=${NGINX_BASE_IMAGE_TAG}
      - echo "${NEW_VAR}"
```

Alternative. Save it to file and print out a file:

```
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo ${NGINX_BASE_IMAGE_TAG} > /tmp/test.value
      - cat /tmp/test.value
```

Comment: @IvanElianto I added an alternative way.

Comment: Neither of these seems to work. CodeBuild is really good at hiding those values!
`[Container] 2020/07/22 16:31:35 Running command cat /tmp/test.value`

`***`

Comment: As @Marcin told, this is by design. However, if you really only need the value from parameter store (for example, I store  docker image tag version in parameter store in this case), it's actually works well. It's just cannot be displayed properly in CodeBuild logs.

In short, even if you see docker push <your ECR repo URL>:***, it's still pushed as expected.